# How soon will Ubuntu update the firefox web browser?

Tags: updates, firefox

The version 45.0.1 was out in 3/16, how soon is Ubuntu to update it in usual?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion

Comment: I was wondering if I should use the ppa until you send me this page, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

45.0.1 is already available for the current development version of Ubuntu (16.04 beta). 45.0 is available for the current supported versions (see [the package index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox)). I'd say it's only a matter of days.